# How to catch a GET param on any page in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the Rails way of catching an HTTP request GET parameter on **any** paths? For example you want to save `...?foo=bar` on: `http://example.org/<PATH>?foo=bar` (`<PATH>` can be anything) into the common `session` object.

Obvious bad solutions I found is adding a shared method to all controller actions or overriding the `ActionController::Base` with a `before_action` - however I believe there must be a better way. Is there any Rails middleware or hook for this?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `before_action` to `ApplicationController` (or whatever you use for a base controller class) and then have your controllers inherit from that.